# Questions about python module

Tags: python

It is my first time learning PyQt5.
While I read code related to PyQt5, I have a question some modules.

Is 'isStarted' a variable or in a module?

```
def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.isStarted = False
        self.isPaused = False
        self.nextMove = None
        self.lastShape = Shape.shapeNone
```

Comment: `self.isStarted` is variable in class/instance but sometimes for variable in class is used word `property`

Answer (score 0):

```py
def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.isStarted = False
        self.isPaused = False
        self.nextMove = None
        self.lastShape = Shape.shapeNone
```

Whenever there is an `=`, rest assured that anything on the left side is a variable. In this case, you are making `isStarted` variable an attribute of `self` which is the class in which your code is in. So you can call it from other classes like: `print(App.isStarted)` (of course, replace `App` with whatever your class is named.